# Finding all files of certain type in Microsoft Outlook 2003

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003

I have a huge inbox in Microsoft Outlook 2003 and I need to find files of specific type from it.
 Lets say I need to find all Microsoft Powerpoint 2010 files. How would one do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately ext:blah is not available in Microsoft Outlook 2003. Currently I have solved this little problem by install Microsoft Windows Desktop Search 4.0 and letting it index Microsoft Outlook mailbox. After the indexer has finished, searching for files in inbox is  smooth as silk.

Answer (score 0):

Type  the following in the search bar  for  emails with attachments
`ext:ppt`
`ext:pptx`

Just replace ppt with whatever file extension you are looking for

Note: `ext:ppt` will include results of `ext:pptx`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help, it seems like youre probably trying to search the usual *.doc way, but as that site says it isnt supported that way, only the ext:doc way..

http://www.msoutlook.info/question/607